# Add comment programmatically in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

trying to create a comment in own module.

```
$comment = new stdClass();
$comment->nid = 555; // Node Id the comment will attached to
$comment->cid = 0;
$comment->pid = 0;
$comment->uid = 1;
$comment->mail = 'email@example.com';
$comment->name = 'admin';
$comment->is_anonymous = 0;
$comment->homepage = '';
$comment->status = COMMENT_PUBLISHED;
$comment->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
$comment->subject = 'Comment subject'; 
$comment->comment_body[$comment->language][0]['value'] = 'Comment body text';
$comment->comment_body[$comment->language][0]['format'] = 'filtered_html'; 
comment_submit($comment);
comment_save($comment);
```

The code causes the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function **node_load()** in
>   BLA/BLA/comment.module on line 1455

node_load() function is in node module which, of course, enabled.

How to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Wierd...Moved module folder into system module directory and error gone away. Solved!

Comment: Where are you placing that code? I've tested it here and it works fine, but if node_load is undefined your code must be executing before the node module. You shouldn't place custom or community modules in the core modules folder.

Answer (score 4):

Try like this:

```
  $comment = (object) array(
    'nid' => $node_id,
    'cid' => 0,
    'pid' => 0,
    'uid' => 1,
    'mail' => '',
    'is_anonymous' => 0,
    'homepage' => '',
    'status' => COMMENT_PUBLISHED,
    'subject' => 'dsk subject',
    'language' => LANGUAGE_NONE,
    'comment_body' => array(
      LANGUAGE_NONE => array(
        0 => array (
          'value' => 'aaa',
          'format' => 'filtered_html'
        )
      )
    ),
  );

  comment_submit($comment);
  comment_save($comment);
```